# Installing 56k USB modem in Windows XP mode

Tags: drivers, windows-xp-mode, usb-modem

I have a [US Robotics 56k USB faxmodem](http://www.usr-emea.com/support/s-prod-template.asp?loc=unkg&prod=5633) which I need installing on my machine. I am running Windows 7 and also have Windows XP mode installed. I have searched a lot and it would seem [it is not compatible with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Hardware&Name=USRobotics%20USR5633A%20USB%20Fax%20Modem&ModelOrVersion=&Vendor=USRobotics&Locale=1033%2C2057%2C3081%2C4105%2C16393&LastSearchTerm=usrobotics%2Busr5633a%2Busb%2Bfax%2Bmodem&BreadcrumbPath=usrobotics%20usr5633a%20usb%20fax%20modem&TempOsid=Windows%207).

There are Windows XP drivers on the USR website, so thought I would try installing it in XP mode, however when trying to attach it as a USB device I get the following error;

[image: XP Mode Error]

(I have tried both the suggestions in the error message)

I have tried the Vista driver from within Windows 7 but I got a BSOD and had to start on `Last Known Good Configuration`